# Extract bits of character in C using limited bitwise operators

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Assume that I can only use the bitwise operators <<, >>, &

I have the following,

```
unsigned char c = 181;
```

I want to print out the bits in this char from most significant bit to least significant bit. How do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a mask and isolate one bit at a time:

```
int i;
char c = 181;
for (i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
{
    putchar((c >> i) & 1 ? '1' : '0');
}
putchar('\n');
```

Comment: An equivalent way would be `(c >> i) & 1`

Comment: You are also better served using `putchar` to output a single *character* rather than calling the variadic function `printf`.

Comment: Noted and implemented. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 3):

There are as many different ways to approach this as you want to explore. Do you want to pad the output? Do you want to include separators? (e.g. `1111-0110`)? Do you want to limit the output to X number of bits? And on and on.

The most basic approach is the one you are asking about, but when implementing a solution, why *hard-code* limitations of `8-bits` when you can write a simple generic routine to handle any `unsigned` type (up to what you specify as the parameter). Also, when *bit-twiddling*, it is recommended to use *exact size types* (e.g. `uint8_t`, ... `uint64_t`) so there is no chance of platform differences. (exact types are defined in `stdint.h`) The corresponding conversion macros for the exact width types are provided in `inttypes.h`.

Putting the pieces together, you could write your print of the *unpadded binary representation* of any type value up to `uint64_t` something like the following:

```
/** unpadded binary representation of 'v'. */
void binprn (const uint64_t v)
{
    if (!v)  { putchar ('0'); return; };        /* handle v = 0 simply */

    size_t sz = sizeof v * CHAR_BIT;            /* set the number of bits */
    uint64_t rem = 0;                           /* value holding remaining bits */

    while (sz--)                                /* for each bit */
        if ((rem = v >> sz))                    /* if bits remain */
            putchar ((rem & 1) ? '1' : '0');    /* output the bit */
}
```

Putting it together with a short example for `c = 181`, you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>     /* for CHAR_BIT */
#include <stdint.h>     /* for exact size type ints */
#include <inttypes.h>   /* conversion macros for exact size types */

/** unpadded binary representation of 'v'. */
void binprn (const uint64_t v)
{
    if (!v)  { putchar ('0'); return; };        /* handle v = 0 simply */

    size_t sz = sizeof v * CHAR_BIT;            /* set the number of bits */
    uint64_t rem = 0;                           /* value holding remaining bits */

    while (sz--)                                /* for each bit */
        if ((rem = v >> sz))                    /* if bits remain */
            putchar ((rem & 1) ? '1' : '0');    /* output the bit */
}

int main (void) {

    uint8_t c = 181;

    printf ("The bits in unsigned char c = '%" PRIu8 "' are:\n\n  ", c);
    binprn (c);
    putchar ('\n'); /* tidy up */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/cbits
The bits in unsigned char c = '181' are:

  10110101
```

Look over all the answers, and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Could avoid the need for the special case of `if (!v) ...` by using a `do { } while (sz);` loop.

Comment: Yes, and I haven't dumped to assembly to check what difference that would make (if any) on code generation. I'll check and if significant, drop a comment.

Answer (score 2):

A *simple* solution that does not involve magic numbers like `8`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_out_the_bits(unsigned char x) {
  if (x > 1) print_out_the_bits(x >> 1);  // print most significant bits first
  putchar("01"[x & 1]);
}

int main() {
  unsigned char c = 181;
  print_out_the_bits(c);
}
```

Output

```
10110101
```

Comment: And I like the array indexing of a string in `putchar` -- slick.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Could have use `putchar('0' + (x&1));` makes more sense but OP imposed a bitwise operator limit.  Hmmm, is `[]` cheating?

Comment: Call it "creativity" instead of "cheating" `:)`